# Google - Ecommerce-analytics not recordinng

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I'm trying to get Google eCommerce analytics set up on an "order successful" page. But I'm having some trouble.

Below is what is currently on the page - anyone know what is wrong?

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

    ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', { 
        'id': '1000',
        'affiliation': 'something',
        'revenue': '200',
        'shipping': '10',
        'tax': '33.32'
    });

    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
        'id': '1000',
        'name': 'red-shoes',
        'sku': 'RS-M',
        'category': 'Mens Shoes',
        'price': '100',
        'quantity': '2'
    });

    ga('ecommerce:send');

    ga('create', 'UA-98536457-1', 'mydomain.co.uk');

    ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ga('create'...)` should be before the `ga('ecommerce...)` calls, otherwise the analytics code won't know which profile id the ecommerce transaction applies to.

Answer (score 0):

```
 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
            ga('create', 'UA-109213877-1', 'auto');

           ga('require', 'ecommerce');
            ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {'id': '','affiliation': 'Corporate Orders','revenue': '14.62','shipping': '0','tax': '0'});
    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {'id': '','name': 'Unbearably Hot Cinnamon Bears','sku': 'Unbearably-Hot-Cinnamon-Bears','category': 'Test','price': '18.50','quantity': '1'});
ga('ecommerce:send');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

This is my code and it is not recording data in analytics. Is there any thing wrong with my code